# How to make sound notification when message receives using multipeer connectivity?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

I am making a bluetooth chat application in which i am using multipeer connectivity framework and i have to use sound notification and also the message will show with notification-

```
#import "MCManager.h"
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation MCManager
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _peerID = nil;
        _session = nil;
        _browser = nil;
        _advertiser = nil;
    }

    return self;
}


#pragma mark - Public method implementation

-(void)setupPeerAndSessionWithDisplayName:(NSString *)displayName
{
    _peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:displayName];

    _session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID];
    _session.delegate = self;
}


-(void)setupMCBrowser{
    _browser = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat-files" session:_session];
}


-(void)advertiseSelf:(BOOL)shouldAdvertise
{
    if (shouldAdvertise)
    {
        _advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat-files"
                                                           discoveryInfo:nil
                                                                 session:_session];
        [_advertiser start];
    }
    else
    {
        [_advertiser stop];
        _advertiser = nil;
    }
}


#pragma mark - MCSession Delegate method implementation


-(void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state{
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"peerID": peerID,
                           @"state" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:state]
                           };

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MCDidChangeStateNotification"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:dict];
}


-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID{
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"data": data,
                           @"peerID": peerID
                           };

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MCDidReceiveDataNotification"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:dict];

        SystemSoundID soundID;
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef ref = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)@"Voicemail.wav", NULL, NULL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(ref, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}


-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didStartReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withProgress:(NSProgress *)progress{

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"resourceName"  :   resourceName,
                           @"peerID"        :   peerID,
                           @"progress"      :   progress
                           };

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MCDidStartReceivingResourceNotification"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:dict];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [progress addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted"
                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                      context:nil];
    });
}


-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didFinishReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID atURL:(NSURL *)localURL withError:(NSError *)error{

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"resourceName"  :   resourceName,
                           @"peerID"        :   peerID,
                           @"localURL"      :   localURL
                           };

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didFinishReceivingResourceNotification"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:dict];

}


-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveStream:(NSInputStream *)stream withName:(NSString *)streamName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
{

}


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MCReceivingProgressNotification"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:@{@"progress": (NSProgress *)object}];
}

@end
```

I write this code in `didReceiveData` to notify sound when receives data but it is not working i am sending the message but not make any sound notification. 
Please help me i am stuck in this problem from last 10 days.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Voicemail" ofType:@"wav"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

Comment: @AayushKatiyar If it works can you check my answer as valid ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass your sound file name in the payload, otherwise default.mp3 for default notification tone.